# Does there exist a finite group $G$ such that all its subgroups are not normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just learned the concept of normal subgroup in group theory, and by Lagrange theorem, I know that if $G$ is finite, and $|G|=n$, then all its subgroups have order $d$ where $d \mid n$

I'm wondering if it's possible that $|G|=n$, but there's no normal subgroup with order $d$ for all $d \mid n$. It's clear that when $n$ is prime this is not true, since this time the only possible subgroups are $\left\{ e \right\}$ and $G$, they are normal subgroups.  What about when $n$ is not prime? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group

Comment: ... and determining all finite simple groups was quite an undertaking, which took decades and thousands of journal pages to complete, called the Classification of Finite Simple Groups.

Comment: The simplest (no pun intended) examples of finite simple groups are the cyclic groups of prime order, and the alternating groups $A_n$ for $n\ge5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When I started as a graduate student may years ago, my supervisor told me firmly that the simplest nonabelian simple groups were not, as widely believed, the groups $A_n$, but the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$,in the sense that we know just about everything there is to say about them (such as a complete description of their subgroups).

Comment: @Derek, good point. I suspect that someone who, like OP, "just learned the concept of normal subgroup in group theory" is more likely to be familiar with $A_n$ than with PSL$(2,p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's possible that $|G|=n$, but there's no normal subgroup with order $d$ for all $d \mid n$.

Well, we clearly have to exclude $d=1$ and $d=n$, since both $\{e\}$ and $G$ itself are normal in $G$.

With this change it becomes an interesting question. Such groups do exist and are called [simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group). Simple groups are building blocks for finite groups, similar to how primes are building blocks for natural numbers.

If $n$ is prime then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a simple group, by the fact that it doesn't even have subgroups between $1$ and $n$. If $n$ is not prime, then there still are examples of such groups, e.g. [the alternating group $A_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) for $n\geq 5$, which is of order $\frac{n!}{2}$, which is not prime.

> What about when $n$ is not prime?

That depends on $n$. It is not hard to see that if $p$ is prime and $n=2\cdot p$, then there is no simple group of order $n$. By the fact that such group would necessarily have a subgroup of index $2$ (a consequence of Cauchy theorem), and such subgroups are always normal (by the fact that left and right cosets form partitionings, which for index $2$ are necessarily equal).

In fact this is a solved problem: all finite simple groups are known. The effort is known as [the classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) and it has one of the largest (in terms of volume) proof in entire history of maths, consisting of tens of thousands of pages.